# Why must $\vec{v} = \frac{\vec{u}\cdot \vec{v}}{\vec{u}\cdot \vec{u}} \vec{u}$ for equality in the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality?

Tags: linear-algebra, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

The Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality is equal when $\lvert\vec{u} \cdot \vec{v}\rvert = \lVert \vec{u} \rVert \lVert \vec{v} \rVert$.

Since $\lvert\vec{u} \cdot \vec{v}\rvert = \lVert \text{proj}_{\vec{v}}\vec{u} \rVert \lVert \vec{v} \rVert$, I reasoned that we must have $\lVert \vec{u} \rVert = \lVert \text{proj}_{\vec{v}}\vec{u} \rVert$ for the equality to hold. Geometrically, this would be possible if $\vec{v} = \alpha \vec{u}$ for any $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. However, my notes indicate that the equality is true only when $\alpha = \frac{\vec{u}\cdot \vec{v}}{\vec{u}\cdot \vec{u}}$.

Where is my reasoning wrong that proves that only the specific $\alpha$ above satisfies the equality? What is the geometric significance of $$\alpha = \frac{\vec{u}\cdot \vec{v}}{\vec{u}\cdot \vec{u}}$$

Comment: The book says: "For all $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$,

$$\lvert\vec{u} \cdot \vec{v}\rvert \leq \lVert \vec{u} \rVert \lVert \vec{v} \rVert$$

Equality holds if and only if $\vec{v} = \alpha\vec{u}$ for $\alpha = \frac{\vec{u}\cdot \vec{v}}{\vec{u}\cdot \vec{u}}$". Maybe I am misinterpreting.

Comment: Sorry my previous comment was wrong, I deleted it. Now: if $v = \alpha u$ then $u\cdot v=u\cdot( \alpha u)=\alpha u\cdot u.$

Comment: How about this link?: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#Proofs

Comment: The condition $\alpha = \frac{\vec{u} \cdot \vec{v}}{\vec{u} \cdot \vec{u}}$ is not really a restriction on $\vec{v} = \alpha \vec{u}$ (all assuming $\vec{u} \neq \vec{0}$). If you just dot product both sides of the equation with $\vec{u}$, you can solve for $\alpha$. That is, the fraction $\frac{\vec{u} \cdot \vec{v}}{\vec{u} \cdot \vec{u}}$ is really just a formula for the computation of this arbitrary $\alpha$.

Comment: @TheoBendit Ok, got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the statement is written in a confusing way. A simpler correct statement would be "Equality holds if and only if $v = \alpha u$ for some scalar $\alpha$.

As Anne Bauval points out, if there exists a scalar $\alpha$ such that $v = \alpha u$, then $u \cdot v = \alpha u \cdot u$ which gives an expression for $\alpha$ in terms of $u$ and $v$. You shouldn't interpret this expression $\alpha = (u \cdot v) / (u \cdot u)$ as a definition of $\alpha$.

Answer (score 1):

The condition you obtained by a geometric reasoning is equivalent to the (only *seemingly* more restrictive) condition of your notes, since (as previously commented) if $$v=αu$$
then $$u⋅v=u⋅(αu)=αu⋅u$$ hence $$\alpha = \frac{u\cdot v}{u\cdot u}$$ (provided $u\ne0$).